# Odd Java Hashcode (with Lombok) Non-Deterministic Behavior

Tags: java, hashcode, lombok

I'm getting some behavior that I don't understand with Java Hashcode (using Lombok).  I've got an abstract object Storable for things that I'm storing in various DataStores.

```
public abstract class Storable implements Serializable {
  ...
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of="url", callSuper=false)
@Slf4j
@ToString(of="url")
public final class Foo extends Storable {

  private URL url;

  public Foo(@NonNull URL url, ...) {

    super();
    this.url = url;
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

When I new up multiple Foos with new Foo(new URL("http:///www.foo.com")) and I iterate over them and check each foo.hashCode() I get the same value.  But if I terminate the program and then start another run, the foos in the new run have a different hashCode value even though they look identical from a data standpoint.  The discrepancy is causing me grief because I'm trying to use hashCode to identify unique objects from run to run.  Perhaps even more oddly, for a given URL that I'm using for testing I'm seeing 1 of the same 4 integers every time.

Am I missing something about either Java's default getHashcode() implementation or Lombok's @EqualsAndHashCode implementation?  Or is there something about URL that would cause it to have a different hashCode value?  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I just noticed your code example `url` is a `String` field but has a `URL` parameter in the constructor. which is it?

Comment: Good catch, it's a URL.  I botched the copy/paste as I was trying to edit so that only the essential bits made it into the question.  FWIW I did try creating URL objects by themselves and calling .hashCode() in different processes and I got the same result each time.

Comment: That's very strange. What Lombok does in this respect is well-defined and tested, see e.g. [before](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/test/transform/resource/before/EqualsAndHashCode.java) and [after](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/master/test/transform/resource/after-delombok/EqualsAndHashCode.java). Create a self-contained example and [file an issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/new) or [post to the group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/project-lombok).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 7 this is probably using the alternate `murmur` hashcode implementation which is not guaranteed to produce the same hashcode across JVM instances (or the same JVM run multiple times)

[Article that discusses the change to hashcode in Java 7](https://jaxenter.com/the-state-of-string-in-java-107508.html)

Relevant section:

> A couple more words about the alternative hash code:
>
> - it isn’t exposed publicly through the String class. You can access it using the (unofficial) sun.misc.Hashing.stringHash32 method
> - unlike the original hash code, hash32 for two strings containing the same characters but running in different JVMs (on the same machine or on different machines) isn’t guaranteed to be the same (in fact most likely it won’t be, since a “HASHING_SEED” value is included in the calculation which is initialized on JVM startup using the current time)
> - the purpose of alternative hash code is to give better performance for HashMap and related classes with String keys and to thwart hash-collision denial of service attacks
> - Its usage isn’t enabled by default. You need to set the “jdk.map.althashing.threshold” property to enable it. If you set this to a value X, then HashMap and related classes with a capacity at least X will use the alternative hashing algorithm.
>
> A word of caution if you want to enable alternative hashing: prior to Java 7u40 (ie. all versions between Java 7u6 and Java 7u39) had a performance issue which meant that HashMap creation while alternative hashing was enabled was slower than needed to be. Thus if you want to enable alternative hashing, ensure that you have the latest Java 7 runtime.

This was added in Java 7u6 but has been removed in Java 8.

Here's the internal implementation of Java 7's murmur hash function  [on grep code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/misc/Hashing.java#Hashing.murmur3_32%28int%2Cchar%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%29).

Here's the link to Java 7's HashMap implementation that uses the new hash code calculation if the key in the map is a String http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.hash%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Wow, fantastic answer.  Thank you!  I debugged this for several hours assuming there was some kind of issue in my code. :)  I'll try it out with a more recent JRE.

Comment: Hmmm, scratch that.  I may have been too hasty in calling this the answer.  This is running against Java 8. I wasn't sure what was on this system, but System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version")) gives me 1.8.0_45.  Per your explanation I shouldn't see this issue in Java 8, correct?

Comment: I don't think so.  I also think you had to explicitly turn on the alternate hash implementation.  Good luck tracking down the problem

Comment: Bummer.  I definitely didn't turn on the alternate hash implementation, at least not knowingly.  I went ahead and unmarked this as the answer for now, but I really appreciate you taking the time to leave this detailed response!

Comment: You're speaking about `String#hash32`, but it's `URL#hashCode` what matters here. Actually, `String#hashCode` didn't change at all, it's just that it gets avoided in some `HashMap`. I'm rather sure that Lombok does not use `hash32`.

Comment: Yes, the original question had a typo where it was `String` instead of `URL` which led to the confusion

Answer (score 2):

The hash code of an object is not in general required to be deterministic.  Only if the documentation of a class *explicitly* says the hash code is deterministic may you assume it is deterministic.

Comment: I've realized that as I've been reading on the subject, but that still leaves one question unanswered.  URL.hashCode() anecdotally seems to return a deterministic value between JVM instances, so why would wrapping that in an object with a Lombok generated hashCode() that only calls URL.hashCode() add nondeterminism?  Perhaps the answer is in the fact that only 4 different integers get generated, even if I spin the JVM up a thousand times?  I dunno, still doesn't make sense to me...